# Move application launchers off desktop?

Tags: 20.04, unity, icons, launcher, games

I have several application launchers for Steam games on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. It's starting to look cluttered when I do screenshares in meetings.

I'd prefer to create a sub directory of the desktop called 'games' and move all the launchers into there. However when I move them, they no longer display nice icons and are no longer launch-able.

I realize that this is because these special .desktop files are specific to the desktop.

So my question is, how do I create similar shortcuts to applications that are **not** .desktop launchers, that will still display the game icon and launch the game... in a directory that is **not** the desktop? (Similar to how Windows lets you just create a shortcut file to any application and put it anywhere.)

Tried searching this and most results talk about symlinks, but I actually need to run a command like `steam steam://rungameid/897730` with a nice icon.

Thank you!

EDIT:
I did add the Applications Menu Gnome extension which is accomplishing the desktop cleanup goal.

Comment: @user68186 yes I can search for them fine and launch them in other standard ways. They are 'discovered' as applications system wide. I just particularly want shortcuts in specific directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a desktop with an "actual desktop", you could always just use the Main Menu editor to make custom menu launchers like these: [image](though they usually come with them)

Comment: Is this GNOME? The procedure may depend on the DE.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi true, this is gnome flashback... MATE desktop also uses the same process

Comment: Thanks that's pretty helpful. I had to install the editor with `sudo apt-get install alacarte`.

Comment: Actually, MenuLibre seems much better. `sudo apt-get -y install menulibre`.

Comment: @Sherri forgive me.. it comes pre-installed on both of my desktops, i didn't think to include the name of the actual package (alacarte). menulibre seems to be better at chasing down icons, which is helpful.